# How to split multiple line text by regex

Tags: regex

I have multiple lines text

```
SUBJECT=Testing001
TEXT=TestingLine001-Test
TEXT=TestingLine002-Test
REFER=Reference001
SUBJECT=Testing002
TEXT=TestingLine003-Test
SUBJECT=Testing003
TEXT=TestingLine004-Test
REFER=Reference002
```

Just want to split text blocks (for this case, three text blocks, "Subject" is the first line of the text block) like as:

```
SUBJECT=Testing001
TEXT=TestingLine001-Test
TEXT=TestingLine002-Test
REFER=Reference001


SUBJECT=Testing002
TEXT=TestingLine003-Test


SUBJECT=Testing003
TEXT=TestingLine004-Test
REFER=Reference002
```

Comment: *regex* isn't a programming language. can you tell us in what kind of application you want to embed this and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: C# is the major language for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?=\bSUBJECT\b)(?!^)
```

You can use this split.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mG8kZ9/9